# CSS -webkit- perspective property for use with moz browser

Tags: css, cross-browser, transformation, mozilla

Using CSS3 transform and transitions I have created a flipping animation.

Moz does not recognise the perspective CSS3 property and so does not flip in 3D as it does with webkit.

Is there anyway to make `-moz` flip as `-webkit` does

SAMPLE::

http://jsfiddle.net/L9wDd/91/

Comment: Have you tried the regular property of `perspective` without the browser prefixes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had just updated to Firefox 18 and applied the `px` to the `-moz-perspective` property and I achieve the same effect as on Chrome:

```
.container {
    position:relative; display:block;
    -webkit-perspective:1000px; -moz-perspective:1000px;
}
```

Also you could apply the standard `perspective` property and that would have the same effect as well.

```
    perspective: 1000px;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the prefix `-moz` in the property perspective. Note that it will only work on Firefox 10+. You can see an example that works on firefox in the following link: https://gist.github.com/4346505 .